# How do I get content and style dynamically from another cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, links

I have the following scenario:

In table1, I have about 100 rows of data, but the 100 isn't fixed, it might vary as new data gets appended. In every row there is a column 'type' which gets its values from table2.

Inside table2 are a couple of type-specific datas and every row is formated in a different foreground-color and background-color.

Now, if the user changes the drop-down-list in table1 for another type, the whole row should get the font, fontweight, text-color and cell-background-color from the selected type-row in table2. Also, if any of these is changed in table2, it should also update in table1.

How do I do this?

Comment: Conditional formatting should be able to do this. What have you tried so far? Please provide some sample data together with your expected results.

Comment: @Kevin: Thats absolutely unnecessary, the setup is very easy: you just need 2 empty tables. The complication is in the ›how to do‹, to which "Conditional formation" is not the answer, because (at least as I know) it cant get its formats dynamically from the source cell.

Comment: This is very necessary. This site is not to solve your problems for you but to help you solve your problem. You have a decent description of the problem but without any sample data it is impossible to help you get your solution.